# Can authority RRs contain anything but NS and SOA, additional RRs anything but A, AAAA, OPT?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm slightly confused about the scope of functionality of authority and additional resource records.

The authority section seems to me to usually contain SOA records (negative response), or NS records (pointing to authorative name servers).

The additional section seems to me to usually translate records that are in either the answer section (MX) or authority section (NS). That's why it usually contains A and AAAA records. But I've also seen it contain OPT headers at times (though I'm not familiar with DNS options).

I've looked through RFC1034 and RFC1035, and as a matter of fact, it didn't contain any other use cases. Are there any more use cases for these sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the main thing to think about to make sense of the sections and which RRs go where is that it's not generally the case that the RR type in itself dictates which section it should go in (at least not unambiguously), but rather that the reason why the RR is added to the response dictates where the RR goes.

Now, of course, only some RR types are relevant for some of these cases, so there does exist a connection, but an RR type can usually exist in different sections depending on the situation.

#### Authority section

Authority information RRs, both in referrals, and in responses from the authority.

Associated RR types: `SOA` (negative response), `NS` (referrals, also when tacked on in authoritative response), `DS` (referrals)
Additionally: `RRSIG`, `NSEC` (or variants `NSEC3`, ...)

#### Answer section

The RRs representing the direct answer to what was queried

Associated RR types: the RR type requested (including `SOA`, `NS`, `DS`, etc if you explicitly query these), or `CNAME` if the name is an alias. (Or whatever exists if `ANY` is requested.)
Additionally: `RRSIG`

#### Additional section

Resource records that were not requested, but are related to the data in the actual response. (Should be used very cautiously by the client.)

Also used when tacking on RRs that hold data for added DNS protocol features like EDNS, TSIG, etc.

Associated RR types: usually `A`/`AAAA` (address records relevant to the actual response)
Additionally: `RRSIG`
DNS protocol expansion: `OPT` for additional DNS headers in EDNS(0), `TSIG` for DNS message authentication, `SIG` for SIG(0) variation of message authentication, etc

RFC1034 and RFC1035 were the original main DNS RFCs, but those are documents from 1987 which obviously do not cover the evolution that has continued from that point to what we have today. There are [many](https://www.statdns.com/rfc/) RFCs that have continued to build on top of that foundation.